# Texmaker images

Tags: image, texmaker

When I open my screenshot file from my taskbar all of the images are available. However, when I open the screenshot folder (which I have re-located to the folder my tex file is in) in Texmaker, it says no preview available. How do I go about this? I havent found any information or ever had a similar problem to this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.